# In this template, how do I make an exception in the for-loop without messing up the iteration?

Tags: html, css, templates, jinja2

I want to add

```
{% for product in collections.best-sellers.products | limit: 9 %}
```

to only effect a 'best-sellers' part of the iteration without messing up the other parts 'collections' that will show.

```
  {% for product in collection.products %}

    {% include 'product-grid-item' %}

  {% else %}
blah blah code...
  {% endfor %}
```

I've tried putting

```
  {% for product in collection.products %}
    {% for product in collections.best-sellers.products | limit: 9 %}
    {% include 'product-grid-item' %}

  {% else %}
blah blah code...
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

But it didn't work and it effected all my pages. Tried messing around but not sure much about this tempalating.

I'm trying to effect this page: http://www.cookstopshop.com/collections/all?sort_by=best-selling

The only experience I have with this is with Jinja 2 in Python and would appreciate some help

Comment: Can you use `{% else %}` without `{%if ` at all?

Comment: What templating language are you using?  The `| limit: 9` is not valid Jinja2 filter argument syntax.